# Scraping data from table with hidden and visible rows

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape [this site](http://%20https://upullrparts.com/inventory/) using Selenium. My code is able to load the table I want, but when I try to pull out the data I am not able to pull data from hidden rows even though the data is visible in the HTML.

This is a summary of the HTML table:

```
<tbody>
    <tr style="">
        <td class="footable-first-column">
            <span class="footable-toggle">
                **column 1 data**
            </span>
        </td>
        <td> **column 2 data**</td>
        .
        . More data
        .
    </tr>
    .
    . More Visible rowas
    .
    <tr style="display: none;">
        .
        . Same data structure
        .
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is the code that I am using to open the table and write the data to a csv file:

```
# Find search year button
searchYearButton = driver.find_element_by_id('searchYearButton')
# Click button
searchYearButton.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(3)

# Find Form
searchForm = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("form[id='searchVehicleForm']")
# Find search inventory button
searchInventoryButton = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='Search']")
# Click search inventory button
searchInventoryButton.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(3)

# Pull data from tables
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='vehicletable1']/tbody")

with open('tableOut.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in table.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr'):
        wr.writerow([d.text for d in row.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')])
```

The output only has the data from the visible rows in the table. The rest is empty comma data. Here is the output:

```
2008,CAMRY,12-31-20,309,SILVER,UG029258,109000,4T1CE30P88U763171
2006,IMPALA,12-07-20,406,BLACK,UG028769,Unknown,2G1WC581469163771
1999,ASTRO,09-30-21,210,WHITE,UG034230,Unknown,1GNDM19WXXB186932
1999,RAV4,09-30-21,316,BLACK,UG034232,Unknown,JT3HP10V5X7109589
2002,CAMRY,09-30-21,316,TAN,UG034236,170168,JTDBE32K620095807
2002,PRIZM,09-30-21,412,GREEN,UG034233,Unknown,1Y1SK54892Z414890
1999,CR-V,09-30-21,316,GREEN,UG034229,203216,JHLRD1866XC051024
2006,TRAILBLAZER,09-30-21,210,MAROON,UG034228,Unknown,1GNDS13S362234605
2007,VOLVO 70 SERIES,09-30-21,316,WHITE,UG034225,Unknown,YV1SW612172625431
2005,EQUINOX,09-30-21,412,BLACK,UG034223,Unknown,2CNDL23FX56129877
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
.
.
.
,,,,,,,
```

I've tried a few different options I saw in other questions, but I haven't had any luck getting something that works. I would greatly appreciate any input or solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the execute_script function to remove the `style="display:none"` from each element. There doesn't appear to be a way to remove them all at once, so they are removed individually.

This is the code that I used:

```
with open('tableOut.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in table.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr'):
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", row)
        wr.writerow([d.text for d in row.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')])
```